# Pass the variable and value from python to bash

Tags: python, bash

I would like to pass the variable "NUMBER_CAMS" and value from my python script to a bash environmental file "env_roadrunner"

following is the code that i have written

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import ConfigParser



os.chdir("/home/vasudev/LTECamOrchestrator_docker/tools/")

NUMBER_CAMS=sys.argv[2]

cmd = "xterm -hold -e sudo /home/vasudev/LTECamOrchestrator_docker/tools/create_pcap_replay_encoder " \
      " /home/vasudev/LTECamOrchestrator_docker/tools/env_roadrunner"

p = subprocess.Popen([cmd] , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Following is my bash script which takes environmental variables

```
#!/bin/bash
    # the name or ip address of the orchestrator
    ORCHESTRATOR_IP="192.168.212.131"
    # the port of the orchestrator
    ORCHESTRATOR_PORT=9000
    # password for the admin user
    ORCHESTRATOR_PASSWORD='.qoq~^c^%l^U#e~'
    # number of cameras to create from this pcap file
     NUMBER_CAMS="$N"
    # three port numbers that are only used internally but need to be free
```

I wanted to pass the value NUMBER_CAMS through my python script but i am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vasudev/PycharmProjects/Test_Framework/Stream_provider.py", line 19, in <module>
    NUMBER_CAMS=sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

any suggestions why i am getting index out of range error

Comment: how do you call your python script? you must provide at least 2 arguments. your script snippet doesn't even show the call to the python script!

Comment: BTW your Popen is highly defective. maybe it works, but I would drop the `[cmd]` for `cmd` or split the args already... but that'll be the next issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I just want to pass the value NUMBER_CAMS= 2 to my script

Comment: that I figured out.But _how are you calling your script ?_

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I am running it through pycharm , usual way of calling the script is python encoder.py

Comment: ok, you have no arguments. Where's the relation between your bash shell and your script? maybe you want `os.getenv("NUMBER_CAMS")`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , My script calls the shell script through cmd string

Comment: so my solution works. but it's not using command line arguments.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` with a list argument. Either split your command into a proper list `["xterm", "-hold", "-e", ...]` and use `shell=False`, or pass the string argument alone `Popen(cmd, shell=True, ...)`.

Comment: Also, your shell script doesn't *take* anything; it just defines a bunch of shell variables. There is no way to inject a different value of `NUMBER_CANS`, for example, into the script without modifying the script itself.

Comment: @chepner , i changed my script and i see no change i still get the error

Comment: What is `$N`? That isn't set in your script or passed via the environment.

Comment: @chepner , $N, is a varible to which i would like pass the value NUMBER_CAMS=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to set the value of `N` in the environment so that your script can see that value to assign to `NUMBER_CANS`.

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import ConfigParser

os.environ["N"] = "2"  # Must be a string, not an integer
cmd = ["xterm", 
       "-hold",
       "-e",
       "sudo",
       "-E",
       "./create_pcap_replay_encoder",
       "env_roadrunner"]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
                     cwd="/home/vasudev/LTECamOrchestrator_docker/tools/"
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that `sudo` ignores the current environment by default when running a command; the `-E` option I added allows `create_pcap_replay_encoder` to see the inherited environment. However, you can only use `-E` if `sudo` is configured to allow the environment to be preserved.